# Extra semicolon near answers header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On all the SE sites that I checked, the text that normally says something like “1 Answer” now says “1 Answer<sup>;</sup>” (with a semicolon seemingly in superscript):

[image: semicolon]

The HTML for that part of the page looks like this (the semicolon is on the fourth line from bottom):

```
            <div id="answers">

                <a name="tab-top"></a>
                <div id="answers-header">
                    <div class="subheader answers-subheader">
                        <h2>
                                1 Answer
                        </h2>
                        <div>
                            <div id="tabs">
        <a href="/questions/18587301/which-is-good-il-editor?answertab=active#tab-top" title="Answers with the latest activity first">
            active
        </a>
        <a href="/questions/18587301/which-is-good-il-editor?answertab=oldest#tab-top" title="Answers in the order they were provided">
            oldest
        </a>
        <a class="youarehere" href="/questions/18587301/which-is-good-il-editor?answertab=votes#tab-top" title="Answers with the highest score first">
            votes
        </a>
</div>
;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: :o somebody made an oopsie!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for noticing. Totally "not" my fault. Pushing a fix

Comment: Annnd it's done.

Comment: I think you meant "Totally not my fault.;"