# There's a stray semicolon in the View of the "Question" page

Tags: bug, design

[image: screenshot]

(It's right after the "Answer" text)

Comment: This has already been reported and a fix is apparently being pushed... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195725/extra-semicolon-near-answers-header